Elliptic problem of Euler Lagrangian form
Let $f, g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be given, $c$ a positive constant, and suppose that $w$ solves the following initial value problem for the wave equation on $\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{cases}
c^{-2} w_{tt}(t,x) - w_{xx}(t,x) = 0 & \text{for } (t,x) \in (0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}, \\
w(0,x) = f(x) & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}, \\
c^{-1} w_t(0,x) = g(x) & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}.\end{cases}
Show that solutions $w(t,x)$ have to have the form $w(t,x) = F(x+ct) + G(x-ct)$ for some $F, G \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.
Let us define
$K(t) := \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |c^{-1} w_t(t,x)|^2 dx, \quad P(t) := \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |w_x(t,x)|^2 dx.$
Show that $t \mapsto K(t) + P(t)$ is constant in $t$ and Show that there exists $T_* > 0$ such that for all $t > T_*$, $K(t) = P(t)$.
Can anyone help me with this nonlinear wave equation, I am stuck at the first problem and I think the second problem should be somehow use energy estimate and the third one I guess is ferdholm alternative?

Its not an 'elliptic' problem. Elliptic problems have a  positive definite matrix of the second order 'd' coefficients.
For the first problem, write
$$(\frac{1}{c^2}\ \partial_{t,t}  - \partial_{x,x})\ f = (\partial_{ct,ct} - \partial_{x,x}) \ f =   (\partial_{ct}  - \partial_{x}) (\partial_{ct}   + \partial_{x}) f =0 .$$
so functions of $z_{\pm}=ct\pm x$ get a zero from one of the differential operators.
Take a linear combination of those functions and time derivative at $t=0$ and represent them by the given start functions amplitude $f(0,x)$ and velocity distributions $\partial_1f(0,x)$ at $ t=0.$
